# How to sort array with special characters or numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I having problems on sorting array. My code works on numbers but is not working well on special characters. I tried also with strcmp() function but no luck. Here is my code:

```
$sortBy = $this->input->get('sortBy') !== NULL ? $this->input->get('sortBy') : "";
$arr_ongoing = $this->getArr($this->array_ongoing, "id");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr-FR");
usort($arr_ongoing, function ($a, $b) use($sortBy) {
    return strcoll($a[$sortBy], $b[$sortBy]); 
});
```

here is my sample array:
    Array
    (
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCLWx.png) => Array
        (
            [arrete_id] => 1
            [etude_id] => 458
            [lastname] => Chambre test
            [crpcen] => 29000
            [ville] => Quimper
        )

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [arrete_id] => 2
        [etude_id] => 361
        [lastname] => PICART et Associé(s)
        [crpcen] => 44007
        [ville] => NANTES
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [arrete_id] => 3
        [etude_id] => 35
        [lastname] => JARNOUEN de VILLARTAY et REGEON-VERGNOUX - SE
        [crpcen] => 22005
        [ville] => SAINT-BRIEUC CEDEX 2
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [arrete_id] => 12
        [etude_id] => 132
        [lastname] =>  LE PAPE et LACOURT
        [crpcen] => 29022
        [ville] => PONT-L'ABBE CEDEX
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [arrete_id] => 13
        [etude_id] => 222
        [lastname] => KERJEAN et Associé(s)
        [crpcen] => 35129
        [ville] =>  BRUZ CEDEX
    )

)
```

[image: output]

Comment: You're going to have to define "not working well", and maybe provide some example text that isn't an image. Also, please explicitly state the encoding of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "special chars" you mean chars specific to a particular language I suggest using `Collator` from the `intl` package of extensions.

For example for Polish standard `sort` of:

```php
$array = [ 'a', 'ą', 'b', 'z' ];
```

will give you:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "a"
  [1] =>
  string(1) "b"
  [2] =>
  string(1) "z"
  [3] =>
  string(2) "ą"
}
```

while sorting using Collator the correct one:

```php
$collator = new Collator('pl_PL');
$collator->sort($array);
```

gives the correct:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "a"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "ą"
  [2] =>
  string(1) "b"
  [3] =>
  string(1) "z"
}
```

If you cannot use the pecl `intl` but using PHP >=7.0.0 you can use this lib:
https://github.com/voku/portable-utf8

for example:

```php
$array = [ 'a', 'ą', 'b', 'z' ];

function mysort($a, $b) {
    return UTF8::strcmp($a, $b);
}

use voku\helper\UTF8;
usort($array, 'mysort');
```

It does not require mbstring or intl to be installed (although suggests it).

You should not rely on `setlocale` as it is based on the locales installed in the particular system and those may not only be not installed, but also their names may differ (between Windows and *nix, but also between *nixes).

Comment: collater class needs configuration on php.ini. is there other way without using collator because I dont have access on php.ini file?

Comment: check out my updated answer, it gives you an example with an purely php library (can include it in the code)

Comment: thx @Bartosz Pacholek. I tried this library and use UTF8::strnatcmp(). it is working now. thx for your help :)